# Why are java interface constants treated as non-public by ConstantName check in Checkstyle

Tags: java, interface, static-analysis, checkstyle

In our project we want to ensure that the private constants always start with **_** (underscore) and rest all do not start with an underscore.
The checkstyle check **ConstantName** fails to treat the interface constants as public and applies the rules of private modifier.
We are using checkstyle 8.35 in our gradle project to analyse java code (OpenJdk 11, Gradle 6.4).
Below is the code snippet of Interface with constants.

```
public interface MyInterface() {
   int MAX_SIZE = 1024;
  
   //Some methods here
}
```

Checkstyle configuration for **ConstantName** check is as below

```
<module name="ConstantName">
  <property name="format" value="^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$"/>
  <property name="applyToPrivate" value="false"/>
</module>
<module name="ConstantName">
  <property name="format" value="^_[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$"/>
  <property name="applyToPublic" value="false"/>
  <property name="applyToProtected" value="false"/>
  <property name="applyToPackage" value="false"/>
</module>
```

Post running the checkstyle analysis the error is reported for `MAX_SIZE` as `Name 'MAX_SIZE' must match pattern '^_[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$'.` while our expectation is **No Errors**.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Checkstyle that should be reported there.

Comment: Thank you @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-. Raised https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/8569

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by a quick scan of the [source code](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/3b73e3467fd7993cfd806fcd7ca44b6abed58dbe/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/naming/AbstractAccessControlNameCheck.java#L84), this is a bug. They're only considering the constant to be public if the keyword `public` is present (which is the case in classes, but not interfaces).

I would suggest reporting this as an issue at https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues

Comment: Thank you @Jeroen Steenbeeke. https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/8569 raised.